# New polygons disappear on saving

Tags: qgis, polygon

I was working in a project (in QGIS) which had rule based style, when I  draw a new polygon it disappears, I now know this was because I didn't assign it a value to comply with the rule based style, but how can I show these polygons so I can delete them?

I tried to open the shapefile without the rule based style and the polygons I drew that disappeared don't show, they also don't appear on the attribute table, I know they are there because when I draw another polygon and assign it a reference, that one disappears and the reference gets allocated to another missing polygon!

Comment: What do you mean by assigning a reference?

Comment: just a reference number to the polygon, column 1 on my attribute table

Comment: did you try adding a null value to the rule based style that you have? some default style so nothing is left out

Comment: Are you working in the correct CRS's, both in your project and your layers?